# "WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be available in the path" in django LiveServerTestCase

Tags: python, django, selenium, unit-testing

I am making django unit test case with LiveServerTestCase. I am trying to use selenium.

I have written following tests.py.

```
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver

class TestChronology(LiveServerTestCase):
    fixtures = ['user-data.json']
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        # cls.selenium = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:\jatin\chromedriver.exe')
        cls.selenium = WebDriver()
        super(TestChronology, cls).setUpClass()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.selenium.quit()
        super(TestChronology, cls).tearDownClass()

    def test_login(self):
        self.selenium.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/')
        username_input = self.selenium.find_element_by_name("username")
        username_input.send_keys('myuser')
        password_input = self.selenium.find_element_by_name("password")
        password_input.send_keys('secret')
        self.selenium.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="Log in"]').click()
```

I have chromedriver.exe in same path, i also put it in C:\Python27\Scripts and set environment variable. Though it gives error.

I am running this command

```
python manage.py test
```

If i keep this tests.py file outside project and run it with following command,

```
python tests.py
```

It run perfect and also open chrome browser.

So anyine can solve this issue or can give any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't use `executable_path` as you have commented? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe, I used it, but gave same error.
from selenium import webdriver
cls.selenium = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:\jatin\chromedriver.exe')

Comment: What about `webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:\\jatin')`?

Comment: @alecxe, i haven't test it yet, i will test it and reply, Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe, i trieed it, but same error. :(